# Chrome extension rejection -- jQuery issue?

Tags: jquery, google-chrome-extension, xmlhttprequest, google-chrome-app, chrome-web-store

We keep getting our extension rejected and are unsure why.

One theory why is that it has to do with our jQuery library (v2.0.2) potentially having code for download or importing scripts that we aren’t using. Is it common for jQuery libraries to include this code by default and is that something that would be flagged if not manually removed?

We got a notice at one point in our project for “If the items are requesting or executing any remotely hosted code (including by referencing remote javascript files or executing code obtained by XHR requests)”, but we stopped getting that description as part of our rejection a few versions ago.

Also, does jQuery need to be executed in our manifest if we executeScript for the jQuery file elsewhere?

Comment: With executeScript no need to specify it in manifest, but I doubt the problem is caused by jQuery. Do you have any `eval` or `Function`-based evaluation of code? Do you fetch/XHR remote scripts? Any of your html reference remote scripts?

Comment: [tag:wOxxOm] thank you for your response! I think the XHR might be an issue. Here is an example of what we are using for a part of our code. Does this fit what yo're talking about with remote scripting that could get flagged?

Comment: var blobRequest = new XMLHttpRequest();
    blobRequest.open('GET', file, true);
    blobRequest.responseType = "blob";
    blobRequest.onreadystatechange = function(){
        if(blobRequest.readyState == XMLHttpRequest.DONE){
            if(blobRequest.status == 200){
                var blob = this.response;
                var previewFile = new File([blob], "xyz.png",{type: "image/png", lastModified: Date.now()});
                formData.append("file", previewFile);
                uploadRequest.send(formData);
            }
        }
    }
    blobRequest.send();

Comment: Looks like an image so why would it be related to remote scripting? Anyway, without seeing at least manifest.json there's nothing I can add.